# tkinter: Returning the (x,y) results of a mouse button click event to be used as a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I am eventually trying to run a code that's a bit more sophisticated than this, but this is the hump I'm trying to get over. I just need to be able to run a code that takes the x,y coordinates of the pixel clicked and records them as either a variable or appends them to a list. For right now I have them set as `L_Click_x` and `L_Click_y`, I would eventually like to be able to add these coordinates to a list or be able to call upon them in the function. Nothing I have tried seems to work, I'm pretty new to this so there's probably something fundamental that I'm just not getting. (Also the red lines that appear are just for visual confirmation of the click)

```
from tkinter import *

def motion(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print("Current Position = ",(x,y))

def LeftClick(event):
    L_Click_x, L_Click_y = event.x, event.y
    redline = canvas.create_line(0,L_Click_y,400,L_Click_y,fill = "red")
    redline = canvas.create_line(L_Click_x,0,L_Click_x,300,fill = "red")
    print("Left Click = ",(L_Click_x,L_Click_y))


root = Tk()

root.bind('<Motion>',motion)
root.bind('<Button-1>',LeftClick)

canvas = Canvas(root, width = "400",height = "300")
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between local variables and global variables?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep track of the first clicked point, until the second is known, and then draw a line segment between the two.
This simple example uses a global variable, and the points are discarded when drawn; you will probably want to use a container to keep track of the line segments, and a program construction that allows you to access it without making it global.

Please note that I bound the events to the canvas instead of root; I changed the imports to avoid cluttering the namespace (as your app grows, you'll be glad you did), and changed the camelcase names to a more pythonic convention.

```
import tkinter as tk


def motion(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print("Current Position = ", (x, y))


def left_click(event):
    global line_segment
    line_segment.append(event.x)
    line_segment.append(event.y)
    canvas.create_oval(event.x+1, event.y+1, event.x-1, event.y-1)

    if len(line_segment) == 4:
        canvas.create_line(*line_segment, fill="red")
        line_segment = []


if __name__ == '__main__':

    line_segment = []

    root = tk.Tk()

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width="400", height="300")
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.bind('<Motion>', motion)
    canvas.bind('<Button-1>', left_click)

    root.mainloop()
```

[image]